# Raspbian get name of devdevice

Tags: python, thermal-printer

I am working on getting a POS thermal printer working.
Communication is done via RS232 (python serial) and ESCPOS.
On windows everythink works fine.
Code runs on windows:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM4')
ser.write("Hello")     
ser.write(chr(10))
```

Now I need to get the devport/devname of the thermal printer using Raspbian.
How to get the name?
lsusb doesn't gave me a valid name.
What to do?
Plug printer to raspi
->run command x?
unplug printer
->run command x?

How to do so?
Check differences?

All the best;

Answer (score 0):

Serial devices in Linux are named `/dev/ttySx`, `S` stands for "serial" and `x` is a port number (like the `4` from `COM4`). Be sure you have the appropriate permissions to read and write to that device.

If you have multiple serial devices, you can inspect the `dmesg` log buffer and look for the last one with:

```
dmesg | grep tty
```

or simply unplug and see what device is removed from `/dev` listing.

Comment: `/dev/tty             /dev/tty        5       0 system:/dev/tty
/dev/console         /dev/console    5       1 system:console
/dev/ptmx            /dev/ptmx       5       2 system
/dev/vc/0            /dev/vc/0       4       0 system:vtmaster
acm                  /dev/ttyACM   166 0-31 serial
ttyprintk            /dev/ttyprintk   5       3 console
pty_slave            /dev/pts      136 0-1048575 pty:slave
pty_master           /dev/ptm      128 0-1048575 pty:master
unknown              /dev/tty        4 1-63 console
ttyAMA               /dev/ttyAMA   204 64-77 serial
` ttyprintk, doesn't work